# Continue segway/switch screen after admob interstitial

Tags: ios, admob

At the end of my game it runs a function to switch you to the finished screen.

View Controller -> Finish view controller

I want to put the admob interstitial in between.

Here was the original code

```
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(1), target: self, selector: "switchScreen", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Here is the code with interstitial

```
if self.interstitial.isReady {
            self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)



        }


        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(1), target: self, selector: "switchScreen", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

This only returns the user to the view controller and does not continue to the finish view controller.

I tried to call the function on dismissal of the ad

```
func interstitialDidDismissScreen(interstitial: GADInterstitial!) {

   print("interstitialDidDismissScreen")
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(1), target: self, selector: "switchScreen", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)


}
```

However that function didn't fire at all.

Am I missing a function or something here?

Here is the switch screen function for reference

```
func switchScreen() {
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())

        let vc : finishViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("finish") as! finishViewController
        vc.yourFinishScore = yourScore
        vc.toPass = toPass
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Have you set the interstitial's delegate? `interstitialDidDismissScreen` won't be called without it.

Comment: Another palm to face moment for myself, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've set the interstitial's delegate.

```
myInterstitial.delegate = self
```

`interstitialDidDismissScreen` won't be called if the delegate is not set.